# Как сделать, чтобы Post id выводился не test.ru/city/28.......?

Tags: php, yii2

как сделать, чтобы Post `id` выводился не `test.ru/city/28` , хотелось бы `test.ru/city/cgthjkgf-28` , как перед `id` сгенерировать случайно буквы и цифры?

Comment: зависит от того, как вы вообще выводите ссылку

Comment: вывожу из базы, нужно как то чтобы сохранялся id не просто цифры по порядку 34 следующее 35, а нужно чтобы так fyfdhjk-34, следующее khfdgjjd-35 и так далее.

Comment: у вас проблема то в чем именно, как сгенерировать случайную строку? или как ее вставить непосредственно в ` href`

Comment: чтобы в ссылке нельзя было подбирать цифры от поста

Comment: проблема в том когда пост просматриваешь к примеру test.ru/city/23, потом если цифру в ссылке поменять на 24 выводится следующий пост, а мне нужно чтобы нельзя было перебирать таким образом посты.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Secury
{
    /**
     * Возвращает случайный набор байтов заданной длины
     *
     * @param int $len
     *
     * @throws \RuntimeException
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function randomKey($len)
    {
        $key = '';
        if (function_exists('random_bytes')) {
            $key .= (string) random_bytes($len);
        }
        if (strlen($key) < $len && function_exists('mcrypt_create_iv')) {
            $key .= (string) mcrypt_create_iv($len, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM);
        }
        if (strlen($key) < $len && function_exists('openssl_random_pseudo_bytes')) {
            $tmp = (string) openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($len, $strong);
            if ($strong) {
                $key .= $tmp;
            }
        }
        if (strlen($key) < $len) {
            throw new \RuntimeException('Could not gather sufficient random data');
        }
        return $key;
    }

    /**
     * Возвращает случайную строку заданной длины состоящую из цифр, латиницы,
     * знака минус и символа подчеркивания
     *
     * @param int $len
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function randomStr($len)
    {
        $key = $this->randomKey($len);
        $chars = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789-_';
        $result = '';
        for ($i = 0; $i < $len; ++$i) {
            $result .= substr($chars, (ord($key[$i]) % strlen($chars)), 1);
        }
        return $result;
    }
}

$s = new Secury;
$randomString = $s->randomStr(10);
var_dump($randomString);
```

Результат записываете вместе с id в базу. Если id числовое поле в бд, то заводите отдельное поле для случайно строки.

Код работает на php 5.6+.

Тест http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b02f85276148967e778f20ecf1a5dd9d70fe1b2c